# VW 2.0 TSI jumped time, could the valves be ok?

Tags: turbocharger, timing, timing-chain, valve-timing, valve-train

I've got a VW CC 2.0 TSI that seems to have had the timing chain tensioner fail causing you to jump time (cranks fast but will confirm tomorrow). Is there any chance that the cylinder head/valves might not be bent, in other words is there any chance that I may be able to simply replace the timing chain(s) and tensioner and retime the engine? I'm kind of asking for what happens in your guys's experience, I'm sure pulling the cylinder head is quite a simple process on this engine I just don't have a lot of tools.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a position where the chain can slip and there will be no damage, but will it have happened there?

So possibilities:

Use a camera through the plug hole to investigate for contact

You can take the head off to see if there is any evidence of contact

Conduct a pressure test on each cylinder - any leaking valves become evident usually

Or just fit a new tensioner and set the timing. At this point do two full rotations of the engine and re-check the timing. Then run the engine. If all is well then fine, if not you have to do the remedial work.

Answer (score 0):

[That engine is an interference engine](https://redlinespeedworx.com/blog/2-0t-tsi-timing-chain-tensioner-failure), so don't turn it over. I suggest you replace the timing components, then do a compression check to see if it bent any valves.